# Wordpress for iOS not getting compiled for Pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, wordpress

I got latest source code from Wordpress svn fork. I get below error while I compile.

ld: library not found for -lPods clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How do I fix this issue? I see all Frameworks in Pods project highlighted red.
Do I need to install anything to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the project's readme](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-iOS):

> Starting with changeset 3633 version 3.2, WordPress for iOS uses
>   Cocoapods (http://cocoapods.org/) to manage third party libraries.
>   Trying to build the project by itself (WordPress.xcproj) after
>   launching will result in an error, as the resources managed by
>   cocoapods are not included. Instead, launch the workspace by either
>   double clicking on WordPress.xcworkspace file, or launch Xcode and
>   choose File > Open and browse to WordPress.xcworkspace.

I stress this:

> **Instead, launch the workspace by either
>   double clicking on WordPress.xcworkspace file, or launch Xcode and
>   choose File > Open and browse to WordPress.xcworkspace.**

Answer (score 0):

If Xcode complains when linking, e.g. Library not found for -lPods, it doesn't detect the implicit dependencies.

Go to Product > Edit Scheme Click on Build Add the Pods static library, and make sure it's at the top of the list Clean and build again If that doesn't work, verify that the source for the spec you are trying to include has been pulled from github. Do this by looking in /Pods/. If it is empty (it should not be), verify that the ~/.cocoapods/master//.podspec has the correct git hub url in it. If still doesn't work, check your XCode build locations settings. Go to Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data -> Advanced and set build location to “Relative to Workspace”.

http://docs.cocoapods.org/guides/getting_started.html